# I have a problem in file handling in java

Tags: java, token

any help will be appreciated.

print some details about fines on it, but the code is not giving me an output.

my code is :

Comment: Use ``Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextToken().trim())``

Comment: Your problem is in string handling rather than file handling.

Comment: @NomadMaker I am trying to write the details of my file and make some changes to it by printing the fine, but my code doesn't work.can you help?

Comment: Then ask another question. Do not edit this one to ask it, but ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class BookLib{

  String userName ;
  String bookName;
  int noOfDays;
  int fine;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BookLib{" +
                "userName='" + userName + '\'' +
                ", bookName='" + bookName + '\'' +
                ", noOfDays=" + noOfDays + '}';
    }
  

}
```

```
class Library{
   List<BookLib> books = new ArrayList<>();
   
  void readDetails() throws IOException{
  
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("fineDetails.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    
    
      String thisLine;
      List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    
     
      while ((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
          lines.add(thisLine);
      }

      for(String readLine: lines){
        StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(readLine, ",");
        BookLib tempBook = new BookLib();
        
        tempBook.userName = stringTokenizer.nextToken().trim();
        tempBook.bookName = stringTokenizer.nextToken().trim();
        tempBook.noOfDays = Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextToken().trim());
        
        System.out.println("BookLib = " + tempBook);
        books.add(tempBook)
      
      }

        br.close();
        fr.close();
      
  }
```

I Hope, Above code, is helping you for handling NumberFormatException and future ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException handling. you may also use try-catch {} for handling these errors.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't parse the String "25 " to an Integer because of the whitespace.
You can remove the whitespace using the [trim](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) method of String like this:

```
    //...
    book[i].userName = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
    book[i].bookName = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
    book[i].noOfDays = Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextToken().trim()); // trim here
    //...
```

I think there is another problem that didn't cause any errors yet, because the `NumberFormatException` occured earlier: You do close the readers `br` and `fr` in the for loop, but they will still be used there. You should move the lines `br.close()` and `fr.close()` down to the end of the method.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.I will close it after the method